# Starting a VM on GCP in Jenkin Pipeline using gcloud

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, jenkins-pipeline

My objective is to create an automated system for test, I want to create a VM in another GCP project to install a standalone Packager on it, to run tests on it from the Jenkins worker.

1. I created a VM on GCP , first I authenticate service account attached to the project, I am using the credentials file by uploading it to git repo which is not safe regarding security and then accessing .json (Credentials) file from Jenkins workspace. Is there any better way to do it.
2. Connection through SSH. How can I connect this VM using SSH, I have attached an Log image. I am running two project One on Jenkins and another on GCP.

[Image is Log when I tried to build Jenkins Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drYiM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that Jenkins doesn't run on GCP. For your first topic, you can use a [plugin in Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/google-oauth-plugin/) where you upload your file and, I'm sure, jenkins keep the secret secrets!

For your second question, you can use [gcloud cli to open a ssh connection](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh).

Comment: I tried using gcloud to open connection but when a pipeline builds it gives error that ssh ,  -> Could not SSH into the instance.  It is possible that your SSH key has not propagated to the instance yet.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can also set manually the SSH key in the metadata and use the related private key when you open your ssh connection. This time, you use ssh directly, not the gcloud command.